# How does Flight framework avoid undefined index error

Tags: php

I was wondering, how does [Flight framework](http://flightphp.com/) avoid undefined index error during runtime?

For instance,

```
$result = Flight::request()->query['no_such_key'];
```

will just return `$result` where `empty($result)` will be true.

However, if I use my own array, I will get **Undefined index**

```
$result = $array['no_such_key'];
```

May I know what technique Flight is using?

Comment: Maybe they just supress the error with `@`?

Comment: Control + click the `Flight` keyword on your file and have a look at their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Flight::request()->query` is not array it's [object](https://github.com/mikecao/flight/blob/master/flight/util/Collection.php) which implements [arrayAccess interface](https://www.php.net/arrayAccess).

For example

```
class Dummy implements ArrayAccess {
    public function offsetExists ( $offset ){}
    public function offsetGet ( $offset ){return $offset;}
    public function offsetSet ( $offset, $value ){}
    public function offsetUnset ( $offset ){}
}

$dummy = new Dummy();

echo $dummy['any_index']; // produce 'any_index' without any errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code: https://github.com/mikecao/flight/blob/master/flight/util/Collection.php, it's implements ArrayAccess interface.